# how do I prevent my Website from being access outside of the company?

Tags: c#, asp.net, network-programming

i have developed an HR Management system in Asp.net With C# for Suppose "Abc" Company pvt ltd which contain some functionality like
Attendance Management; i.e. tracking when employeew login into the system then system stores login time of employee and when employee Checkout from the system then system records log out time of system for employee.

But problem is when i will Host this Website on Server then if employee is not present on any day then he/she can 
access website from his/her home and still can perform login and logout with LoginId and Password from the system
and remain present though not present 
in company.

I have suppose 5 Computer in my Abc Pvt ltd then How do i allow only those 5 pc to gain access those websites and not from outside the company??

So any solution???

Comment: Doesn't the company have a dynamic IP *range*? Can't you just restrict access to that range?  On the webserver itself, or through the network just don't allow any outside traffic to be routed to the webserver.

Comment: @BillDinger:ok forget about dynamic ip.but still how do i restrict from outside the company??

Comment: @MariaPithia we need more data including network architecture, server architecture, and program itself including what authentication mechanisms you are using.

Comment: @BillDinger I am using Asp.net Membershipfor authentication.can i restrict this from my source code??

Comment: No, Asp.NET Membership will not work. You'll need to do it on the webserver, the firewall, or inside the code itself by running anther check to retrieve IP address and see if it matches the allowed or disallowed range. JasonW's suggestion on using ip address filters in web.config is probably your "easiest" best

Comment: @GrantWinney:why this question is put as off-topic.could you please tell me as i have clearly told in my question regarding source code

Comment: @GrantWinney:please see solution provided by Jason like this link which gives solution in the form os source code:https://www.stokia.com/support/misc/web-config-ip-address-restriction.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A firewall that restricts access to the web server to traffic within your company intranet is the best approach. As an added bonus, the firewall rules should also prevent VPN traffic from the server IP as well so that the employee cannot bypass the firewall by accessing the VPN tunnel your company may have.

Comment: but how do i configure this firewall for hr management system??

Comment: You'll probably want a network engineer to do it right. An easy alternative to a firewall (which is best) is to use IP restrictions in the web.config. You'll have to get the right subnet mask for your internal network IPs, but this link should help: https://www.stokia.com/support/misc/web-config-ip-address-restriction.aspx

Comment: but can u give me some details regarding your ans like how this firewall will that task like some detail description if possible

Comment: A firewall would have to be installed onto your network between your ISP and your company network. Then rules would be configured on the firewall device that restricts the flow of network traffic into and out of your company network. A simple Cisco PIX firewall would probably do the trick, but hopefully your company already has at least one to protect your intranet. A google search can help you get the basics, such as http://computer.howstuffworks.com/firewall.htm